# Running stored procedure in a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, read-uncommitted

I setup a `DbContext` where I have this code:

```
base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;");
```

in the context constructor. I execute a stored procedure like this:

```
return base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mystoredprocedure");
```

but I'm getting a deadlock because this executes in a read committed connection.

I'm asking is there any reason why the stored procedure would run in a read committed fashion when it is part of the same context that has the read uncommitted connection.

Comment: Be careful, a stored procedure can define its own isolation level. Also, mystoredprocedure can call other stored procedures that execute with another level.

Comment: Also, setting NOLOCK's across the board does not guarantee that you will avoid deadlocks.

Comment: The two statements run their own sessions. Also, I wouldn't run any database access code in a context's constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) instead as follows:

```
using (var txn = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted })
{
    return base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mystoredprocedure");
}
```

Or using [Database.BeginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.begintransaction(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
using (var txn = base.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))
{
    return base.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC mystoredprocedure");
}
```

EF wraps each `ExecuteSqlCommand` in its own transaction by default. That's why the first call to `SET ISOLATION LEVEL` does not extend the transaction to the 2nd call to `EXEC proc`.  More about the working with transactions in EF in the link below:

> **Entity Framework Working with Transactions**
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx